# Binary rejected because of missing username and password for test account in Test information TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

I submitted my app for review for external testing and the binary got rejected due to missing username and password for a test account in Test Information tab of testFlight.

Here is the response in Resolution Center in App Store connect. I have added the username and password in test information tab and replied in Resolution Center as suggested.

Do I need to submit the app for review again?. As the status of binary shows rejected.

**From Apple**
2. 1 Performance: App Completeness

**Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed**

We have started your beta app's review, but we were unable to successfully access all or part of your app.

In order for us to continue the review, we need to have a way to verify all app features and functionality. Typically this is done by providing a demo account that has access to all features and functionality in your beta app. It is also acceptable to include a demonstration mode that exhibits your app’s full features and functionality. Note that providing a demo video showing your beta app in use is not enough for us to continue the review.

**Next Steps**

To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide a user name and password in the Beta App Review Information section of App Store Connect. Please be sure that the demo account includes content that demonstrates the features and functionality available in your app.

To provide demo account information:

- Log in to App Store Connect
- Click on "My Apps"
- Select your app
- Navigate to the "TestFlight" tab
- Select “Test Information”
- Scroll down to “Beta App Review Information”
- Select the "Sign-in required" box
- Enter demo credentials in the "User Name" and "Password" fields
- Click “Save”
- Reply to this message in Resolution Center

Comment: What are you waiting for?  Why don't provide them with test account information?

Comment: I have provided them with test information and replied in resolution center as suggested in next steps. My question is do I need to submit the binary again as status is rejected in TestFlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After entering the Test Information, all you have to do is reply to the message in Resolution Center. They will get back to you and update the status accordingly.

However, if you would like to expedite the app review, sometimes it's faster to just submit a new build.